# Textbox pin to top when i click on it

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a simple TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="PART_txtBx" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  />
```

and from codebehind i add some text every while:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
    dt.Start();
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PART_txtBx.Text += "hi\n";
}
```

when i click on the textbox it automatically put the scrollbar on top when i add some text to it.

if I handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event like this:

```
private void PART_txtBx_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

the textbox works normally but i can't (of course) select any text.

any ideas to prevent this behavior?

EDIT 1:
I noticed when the textbox is created there isn't any caret in it even if it has got focus. the caret is shown only when the click is executed but i can't find what's changed inside the textbox after the click. 
My TextBox is read only so i don't need the caret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i created my own CustomTextblock for resolving this issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CE.EthernetMessagesManager.Views
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private int realCaretIndex = 0;
        private bool triggeredByUser = false;
        private bool isScrollingWithMouse = false;

        public CustomTextBox()
            : base()
        {
            this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
            this.PreviewMouseMove += CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseMove;
            this.PreviewMouseWheel += CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseWheel;
            this.TextChanged += CustomTextBox_TextChanged;
            this.LostFocus += CustomTextBox_LostFocus;

            this.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.ScrollChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((X, S) =>
            {
                if ((S as ScrollChangedEventArgs).VerticalChange != 0 && triggeredByUser)
                {
                    TextBox textBox = (X as TextBox);
                    int newLinePosition = 0;
                    newLinePosition = (int)(((S as ScrollChangedEventArgs).VerticalChange + textBox.ExtentHeight) / (textBox.FontSize + 2));

                    realCaretIndex += newLinePosition * ((S as ScrollChangedEventArgs).VerticalChange < 0 ? -1 : 1);
                    if (realCaretIndex < 0)
                        realCaretIndex = 0;

                    textBox.CaretIndex = realCaretIndex;
                    triggeredByUser = false;
                }
            }));
        }

        void CustomTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        void CustomTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            textBox.CaretIndex = realCaretIndex;

            var max = (textBox.ExtentHeight - textBox.ViewportHeight);
            var offset = textBox.VerticalOffset;

            if (max != 0 && max == offset)
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    textBox.ScrollToEnd();
                }),
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
        }

        void CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            triggeredByUser = true;
        }

        void CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isScrollingWithMouse)
            {
                TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
                realCaretIndex = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(textBox), true);
            }
        }

        void CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            isScrollingWithMouse = false;
        }

        void CustomTextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            realCaretIndex = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(textBox), true);
            triggeredByUser = true;
            isScrollingWithMouse = true;
        }
    }
}
```

this CustomTextBox also pin the scrollbar to the bottom when i manually put it to bottom. 
the xaml:

```
            <v:CustomTextBox 
                IsReadOnly="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                />
```

Sadly with this implementation selection is broken. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

May: `PART_txtBx.CaretIndex =PART_txtBx.Length;`

or: 
`PART_txtBx.SelectionStart = PART_txtBx.Text.Length;
PART_txtBx.ScrollToCaret();`

[ScrollToEnd().](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx)
with textbox_changed event

Comment: PART_txtBx.SelectionStart = PART_txtBx.Text.Length; will pin it to the bottom and i don't want it

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to extend your TextBox control to add PreviewTextChanged event, like it is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234703/WPF-TextBox-with-PreviewTextChanged-event-for-filt). On PreviewTextChanged you will have to remember SelectionStart and SelectionLength
2. Handle event ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged for your TextBox:

   ```
   ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="OnScrollChanged" <!--in xaml-->


   private void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       // here you could prevent scrolling
       isOnBottom = (sender as TextBox).VerticalOffset + (sender as TextBox).ViewportHeight == (sender as TextBox).ExtentHeight;
   }
   ```
3. Handle TextChanged event:

   ```
   TextChanged="OnTextChanged"

   private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (isOnBottom) (sender as TextBox).ScrollToEnd();
       // and here you can select text that was selected earlier
       // by using remembered SelectionStart and SelectionLength
   }
   ```
4. In the case of manual text entering you will have to prevent text selection

Hope, it helps